# QGIS field-calculator replace function

Tags: qgis, field-calculator

I've got a Shapefile containing contourlines which I would like to style differently according to their value. For that reason I created a field named "100s" where I would like to give values from 0=25m-lines, 1=100m-lines and 2=500m-lines.
For doing that I tried the "replace" function with this syntax:

```
NAME="4600" OR NAME="4700" OR NAME="4800"  replace('NULL','NULL','1')
```

but QGIS gives the following error: "*syntax error, unexpected FUNCTION, expecting $end*". When I then set "$end, the error message is the same. Any suggestions how to resolve that?
Thanks in advance,
Ralf

Answer (score 2):

It's giving you that error because it's the wrong syntax. The `OR` and `AND` keywords return true or false. The replace function is for strings so you don't really need it here. What you are looking for is the case expression:

```
CASE WHEN NAME="4600" OR NAME="4700" OR NAME="4800" THEN 1 END
```

*Note: You need to be running the dev build of QGIS to get that function*

Comment: CASE WHEN expressions seem to be working with 1.8. as well. Either that or I am using a devbuild in disguise...

Comment: They might work in 1.8 I lost track when they were added.

Comment: Hello Nathan,thank you very much! I tried this solution after installing the latest version but infact I didn't get that function. Since I'm running a MAC I looked for the dev build at kynchaos but I wasn't shure which one to choose ... could you please provide a link to the working version? Thanks again,

Comment: I just checked..  CASE WHEN works on 1.8 under Mac.